# Laravel's Custom Validation $parameters returning null

Tags: laravel, validation, parameters, null, laravel-5.4

I'm creating a custom validation **customVal** on the input field **username**. I'm sending other input as a parameter, but the value of the parameter is being received as null.

In my controller I have:

```
$this->validate(request(),[
  'username' => 'customVal: firstname',
]);
```

And on app\Providers\AppServiceProviders I'm dumping the first parameter as a test:

```
public function boot()
{
  \Validator::extend('customVal', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
  {
    dd( Request::get($parameters[0]) ."-". request($parameters[0]) ."-". Input::get($parameters[0]) ."-". $parameters[0] );
    return true;
  });
}
```

which shows

> "--- firstname"

...**the value is null**, however I can get it's name (firstname). And just to make sure, when I dump this on the controller:

```
dd( $request->get('firstname') ."-". request('firstname') ."-". Input::get('firstname') ."-". 'firstname' );
```

I get:

> "myname-myname-myname-firstname"

**So that's basically it, I can't work on the custom validation because I can't get any values.**

And I'm guessing the same happens when I try to use the **require_without_all** validation. Because it doesn't recognize it's parameters (what I write on the fields)

Comment: Remove the space in between `:`  and `firstname` in your validation array.

Comment: That solved! thanks a lot, I can't believe all the hours I wasted on this. Can I accept your comment as the right answer?

Comment: I made it an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space in between `:` and `firstname` in your validation array.